# Problem writing accented words in Code Editor

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, mac, ide

In Brazilian Portuguese (PT-BR) it's common for words to have accents, as in "coleção", which means collection.

I use macOS and whenever I need to write some accented word like "índice" to comment out a line of code, I run the same problem.

When trying to accentuate a letter (e.g., `á`), what I get in the Code Editor is `´áa`, and when using Windows this didn't happen.

Is there any setting I need to change to make this problem stop happening?

Comment: Probably an encoding setting in your code editor (should be configured to utf-8).

Comment: @PepeNO I don't know how I can change this setting in a web IDE like [Code Editor](https://earthengine.google.com/).

Comment: I did some tests on Earth Engine Code Editor over Firefox 93.0 in my Ubuntu 20.04 computer and there's no problem writing non standard characters. I suppose that it's a macOS  problem; try using other web browser than Safari or change you OS's base language or your keyboard layout.

Comment: No progress so far. I tested it in Safari and Google Chrome and there was no difference. I also tried changing the keyboard layout and it remained the same.